# Subtracting current date from column to show in oracle apex classic report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a very simple question but since i am not familiar with SQL or PL/SQL, i got no idea to do that.

In my Oracle APEX Application, I am loading data from a table into a CLASSIC REPORT through setting Local Database/SQL Query as source.

I have to make 4 columns from data of 2 columns stored in a table. I can load 3 without any issue using the below simple statement:

```
Select TaskName, DueDate, DueDate - 3 as ReminderDate

from table_name
```

Fourth column should be "RemainingDays" which equals to DueDate-current date, I have tried writing DueDate - Sys_date and DueDate - current_date in the above statement to get the fourth column but probably its not the correct way as i get error instead of all 4 columns. (I am doing in it basic excel/dax way). Any Help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract a date from another date, Oracle returns a number which is the number of days between the two dates.

One thing to note when using **SYSDATE** or **CURRENT_DATE** is that you may get different results if your user is not in the same timezone as the database.  **SYSDATE** returns the current time of the database. **CURRENT_DATE** returns the current time of the user whatever timezone they may be in.

If possible, try building the query in a tool such as SQL Developer, get it working there, then build your Classic Report in APEX.  If you are still receiving an error, please share the error you are receiving as well as the query you are using.

#### Example

```
--Start of sample data
WITH
    t (task_name, due_date)
    AS
        (SELECT 'task1', DATE '2020-9-30' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'task2', DATE '2020-9-28' FROM DUAL)
--End of sample data
SELECT task_name,
       due_date,
       due_date - 3                   AS reminder_date,
       ROUND (due_date - SYSDATE,2)     AS days_remaining
  FROM t;
```

#### Result

```
   TASK_NAME     DUE_DATE    REMINDER_DATE    DAYS_REMAINING
____________ ____________ ________________ _________________
task1        30-SEP-20    27-SEP-20                    13.66
task2        28-SEP-20    25-SEP-20                    11.66
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution as well as the really valuable information about difference between sysdate and current_date (It really matters a lot for a naive like me) Really Appreciated.!!